# Postfix config for relay

Tags: postfix, configuration, load-balancing

I have a complex setup and I wondered if I could get some advice on postfix config. All adresses made up of course.

I have server A running a web service on mywebsvc.com 1.1.1.1

I have a postfix mta on a private server 2.2.2.2 set to be smtp server for A, handling it's mail (because sendmail on A is insufficient as I wanted to configure and set up mta with DKIM). Postfix should relay ALL mail sent out from 1.1.1.1 as it is the official mta for this service. It should accept requests from nowhere else - it is not an open relay.

main.cf includes the following:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname myhostname = mywebsvc.com
mydestination = $myhostname, mywebsvc.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 1.1.1.1
```

/etc/mailname contains mywebsvc.com

All was well, but then we moved the server 1.1.1.1 mywebsvc.com behind a load balancer 5.5.5.5 and altered DNS for the web service to be: mywebsvc.com 5.5.5.5

How should I alter postfix to account for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the load balancer is going to send out mail so the origin address is probably still going to be 1.1.1.1 - from the point of view of postfix mail will usually be coming from the primary IP of the web server unless it has been configured otherwise.

Comment: Makes sense, I was just a bit worried in case postfix was doing any reverse DNS lookups on sender name, as they would not match.

Comment: Not by default. you would have to configure that explicitly.

Comment: I have "smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination " but that should be ok as mynetworks is correct, yes ?

Comment: That should be correct.